# Get list of filenames via Tasker

Tags: tasker

I'm using Tasker and have a step of List Files. I grab that result and stuff it into `%files`. I then go into a For loop reading `%files` and under items `%files()`. However, this is giving me the full path to the files such as `/storage/emulated/0/Tasker`. All I'd really like is the file name. Is there a step I can do before I enter this loop to truncate the variable results?

Goal would be to just get a list of file names and not the full path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `Variable Split` action with a splitter of `/` to get the pieces, then use `%VAR(<)` to get the filename. If the fact that the full filename is in an array already gives you problems, copy the array element into a non-array variable first.

From your comments, it sounds like you have this code:

```
List files Dir /storage/Tasker/project/test/ Variable %files match *.wav
For Variable %files Items %files()
  Variable Split Name %files Splitter /
  Popup Text %files(<)
End For
```

It's probably not a good idea to use %files as both the "Variable" and the "Items" portion of the For loop. Try using %file for the Variable, then replace all references to %files inside the loop with %file.

Please correct me if I've not captured your code correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I just used the replace function but left the replace string blank. I chose to replace the directory path with nothing and that left me with an array of filenames.