# How can I get a list of files in a directory as text?

Tags: applications, files

I have a folder containing a large number of MP3 files. I want to export a list of all the filenames of files in that folder, so I can then send it by email etc. This can be either copying to the clipboard or saving to a text file.

Couple of very crude suggestions come to mind:

- I could try connecting via USB to my (Windows) computer and running "dir > listing.txt" at a command prompt
- Install Terminal Emulator/IDE and run "ls > listing.txt"

However I tend to think there must be a better way to do this. Does anyone know of an app which has a feature to do this, for example?

**NOTE**: Most of the MP3 files do not have correct ID3s. So I'm really after the filenames as opposed to any way of exporting the media information.

Comment: Should you choose Tasker, you can follow this method: [Get list of filenames via Tasker](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/45597) or use Code -> Run Shell to try the command-line method.

Comment: See [Where to ask for app recommendations?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/2060)

Comment: The besy way is Method 2 you mentioned. It's easy enough if you make an alias in shell.

Answer (score 1):

There is simple method for getting list of files in any folder in Android -

Create FTP file connection between your android phone and Windows PC version of Filezilla.

in Filezilla interface, Select your desired folder from remote site pane and drag it to bottom pane of file transfer status.

Now in Queued files pane,choose export option.It will by default save in XML format.Once export xml file created,use Office Excel to getting proper format for edit.